# Azure Load Test: JMeter script that leverages the external JAR to convert the JPG (java.nio.file.NoSuchFileException)

Tags: jmeter, azure-load-testing

I have the following JMeter based Azure Load Test which leverages the external JAR to convert the given JPG into DICOM(Type of file)

**Note:** The custom JAR(Dicom JAR) works without any issues when tested separately outside JMeter.

**Note:** This custom JAR takes two arguments, input and output files.

**JMeter - Preprocessor(Groovy based)**

```
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import org.apache.commons.lang3.RandomStringUtils;

String ext = "dcm";
String outputFilePath = String.format("%s.%s", RandomStringUtils.randomAlphanumeric(8), ext);

try {
    log.error("Current Path : " + System.getProperty("user.dir")); 
    
    String command = "java -jar Dicom.jar Images-1-min.jpg " + outputFilePath;
    
    log.error("Command is: " + command);

    def process = command.execute();
     
    // Capture and log the process output
    def output = new StringBuilder();
    process.waitForProcessOutput(output, System.err);
    process.waitFor();

    // Log the process output
    log.error("Process output: " + output.toString());

    def p = "ls -R".execute();

    
    // Capture and log the process output
    def o = new StringBuilder();
    p.waitForProcessOutput(o, System.err);
    p.waitFor();
    
    log.error("List Directory : " + o.toString());

    try {
        byte[] binaryData = Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get("output.dcm"));
        
        sampler.getArguments().removeAllArguments();
        sampler.addNonEncodedArgument('', new String(binaryData), '');
    
        // Set the Content-Type header (optional, only if required by the server)
        sampler.setPostBodyRaw(true);
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        log.error("Error modifying and sending DICOM file: " + ex.getMessage());
        throw ex;
    }

} catch (Exception e) {
    log.error("Error executing command: " + e.toString());
}
```

[image]

**Config.YAML:**

```
displayName: DICOM
testPlan: DICOM Load Test.jmx
description: ''
engineInstances: 1
testId: fcba51b1-b4fd-4ae7-a3c2-694080bfd662
splitAllCSVs: False
configurationFiles:
- Dicom.jar
- output.dcm
- Images-1-min.jpg
failureCriteria: []
env:
- name: SUBSCRIPTION_KEY
  value: xxxxxxx
- name: APIM_FHIR_URL
  value: xxxxxxx.azure-api.net
- name: TENANT_ID
  value: xxxx
- name: THREADS_NUM
  value: 1
- name: THREADS_LOOP
  value: 1
autoStop:
  errorPercentage: 90
  timeWindow: 60
```

As you see, I have uploaded all the required files

[image]

I am getting the following error while executing the load test

```
2023-08-15 12:23:22,241 WARN o.a.j.JMeter: LogLevel: INFO
2023-08-15 12:23:22,918 WARN c.a.c.j.j.c.MALTListener: TEST STARTED EVENT - received
2023-08-15 12:23:23,139 WARN c.a.c.j.j.c.MALTFileWriterListener: Received Event testStarted
2023-08-15 12:23:23,150 WARN c.a.c.j.j.c.MALTAutostopListener: MALT autostop test started with error rate 90 for 60s.
2023-08-15 12:23:24,650 ERROR o.a.j.m.J.Convert JPG to DICOM and set it as a Body: Current Path : /
2023-08-15 12:23:24,651 ERROR o.a.j.m.J.Convert JPG to DICOM and set it as a Body: Command is: java -jar Dicom.jar Images-1-min.jpg xaNzytIY.dcm
2023-08-15 12:23:24,692 ERROR o.a.j.m.J.Convert JPG to DICOM and set it as a Body: Process output: 
2023-08-15 12:23:24,909 ERROR o.a.j.m.J.Convert JPG to DICOM and set it as a Body: List Directory : .:
./jmeter/lib/ext:
ApacheJMeter_bolt.jar
ApacheJMeter_components.jar
ApacheJMeter_core.jar
ApacheJMeter_ftp.jar
ApacheJMeter_functions.jar
ApacheJMeter_http.jar
ApacheJMeter_java.jar
ApacheJMeter_jdbc.jar
ApacheJMeter_jms.jar
ApacheJMeter_junit.jar
ApacheJMeter_ldap.jar
ApacheJMeter_mail.jar
ApacheJMeter_mongodb.jar
ApacheJMeter_native.jar
ApacheJMeter_tcp.jar
Dicom.jar
azure-loadtesting-getsecret-0.0.2.jar
jmeter-plugins-autostop-0.1.jar
jmeter-plugins-casutg-2.10.jar
jmeter-plugins-cmn-jmeter-0.7.jar
jmeter-plugins-dummy-0.4.jar
jmeter-plugins-graphs-additional-2.0.jar
jmeter-plugins-graphs-basic-2.0.jar
jmeter-plugins-malt-2.4.jar
jmeter-plugins-manager-1.8.jar
jmeter-plugins-tst-2.6.jar
json-lib-2.4-jdk15.jar
log4j-layout-template-json-2.17.2.jar
readme.txt
./root/artifacts:
Dicom.jar
Images-1-min.jpg
jmeter.log
logs
metrics
output.dcm
results
testplan.jmx
2023-08-14 20:38:56,306 ERROR o.a.j.m.J.Convert JPG to DICOM and set it as a Body: Error modifying and sending DICOM file: output.dcm
2023-08-14 20:38:56,307 ERROR o.a.j.m.J.Convert JPG to DICOM and set it as a Body: Error executing command: java.nio.file.NoSuchFileException: output.dcm
2023-08-14 20:38:56,398 WARN o.a.j.u.SSLManager: Keystore file not found, loading empty keystore
2023-08-14 20:38:57,388 WARN c.a.c.j.j.c.MALTListener: TEST ENDED EVENT - received
2023-08-14 20:38:57,399 WARN c.a.c.j.j.c.MALTListener: TEST ENDED EVENT - uploading jmeter.log file
2023-08-14 20:38:57,432 WARN c.a.c.j.j.c.MALTListener: TEST ENDED EVENT - completed
2023-08-14 20:38:57,433 WARN c.a.c.j.j.c.MALTFileWriterListener: Received Event testEnded
2023-08-14 20:38:57,435 INFO o.a.j.r.Summariser: summary =      1 in 00:00:03 =    0.4/s Avg:  1008 Min:  1008 Max:  1008 Err:     1 (100.00%)
```

I could see the custom JAR (**Dicom.jar**) file under **./jmeter/lib/ext** folder *but I don't see* **output.dcm** and **Images-1-min.jpg** anywhere.

Comment: Could you provide log from line 9? I don't think String has a method `execute()`

Comment: https://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/groovy-jdk/java/lang/String.html#execute()

Answer (score 0):

I'm able to "see" the files are under `/root/artifacts` folder

[image]

Also given your "custom" Dicom.jar is a Java library you can invoke its [main method](https://www.javatpoint.com/java-main-method) or the relevant conversion function directly from Groovy without having to run the command-line interpreter, in this case your test will be cross-platform.

More information:

- [Apache Groovy: What Is Groovy Used For?](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/apache-groovy)
- [How to Reuse Your JMeter Code With JAR Files and Save Time](https://dzone.com/articles/how-to-reuse-your-jmeter-code-with-jar-files-and-s)